# In Apache Beam, can PCollections be reused? Will they be recomputed or can they be cached

Tags: caching, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, materialized-views

I am using Apache Beam on GCP Dataflow. I want to use a PCollection multiple times but I'm worried that it might recompute an expensive PCollection. I can't find a "materialize" or "cache" transform in Apache Beam documentation.

```
import apache_beam as beam

# Set up a pipeline and read in a PCollection
p = beam.Pipeline()
input_data = p | beam.io.ReadFromText('input.txt')
reused_data = input_data | beam.Map(some_expensive_function)
  
# Write the outputs to different files
reused_data | beam.io.WriteToText('output1.txt')
reused_data | beam.io.WriteToText('output2.txt')

# Run the pipeline
p.run()
```

What will happen here? Will it recompute my data or will it cache my data? What if I don't have enough memory on my machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the pipeline as written, nothing will be cached or re-computed (modulo failure recovery). Though the details are left up to the runner, most runners do what is called [fusion](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/glossary/#fusion).  In particular, what will happen in this case is roughly

1. Get first element from input.txt.
2. apply some_expensive_function, resulting in some element X.
3. write X to output1.txt
4. write X to output2.txt
5. [go back to step 1]

If there were other DoFns between 2 and 3/4, they would be applied, element by element, and their outputs fully taken care of, before going back to step 1 to start on the next element. At no point is the full `reused_data` PCollection materialized, it's only materialized one element at a time (possibly in parallel across many workers of course).

If for some reason fusion is not possible (this happens with conflicting resource constraints or side inputs sometimes) the intermediate data is implicitly materialized to disk rather than re-computed.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know! Great to hear that Beam/Dataflow with automatically materialize to disk. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `reused_data` is computed once, and then the same `PCollection` and data will be sinked in the 2 `GCS` buckets.

```
              reused_data  
          |                 |
          |                 | 
          |                 |
 Write GCS bucket 1    Write GCS bucket 2
```

Each sink will traverse the `reused_data` pcollection to write the result to cloud storage bucket.

If you have to use expensive data on your input `PCollection`, I recommend you using the `Dataflow` runner instead of `DirectRunner` in your local machine.

`Dataflow` runner will treat your data in parallel, autoscaling and with multiple `Compute Engine` VMs if necessary.

Comment: Thanks - do you know where I can read more about this behavior? Are there times when the pcollection is NOT cached - say because it uses too much memory?

Answer (score 1):

As Mazlum Tosun already answered, your PCollection `reused_data` is written twice. However, I wanted to point out that the PCollection may only be distributed along as a pointer. Consequently, this might lead to incorrect behavior if you want/start to manipulate your Pcollection in one of the branches of your pipeline.

For example, if you run this code (e.g., [here](https://play.beam.apache.org/))

```
import apache_beam as beam
    
class ManipulatePcoll(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    element[1] = 55
    yield element
    
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  main = (
    pipeline
    | "init main" >> beam.Create([[1,2,3]])
  )
    
  # pipeline branch 1
  (
    main
    | "print original result" >> beam.Map(print)
  )
      
  # pipeline branch 2
  (
    main
    | beam.ParDo(ManipulatePcoll())
    | "print manipulated result" >> beam.Map(print)
  )
```

you get as a result

```
[1, 55, 3]
[1, 55, 3]
```

since `main` in branch 1 points to the same memory as in branch 2.

However, there are cases for which the PCollection is actually serialized and copied, e.g. when distributing data between different workers (see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/model/#serialization-and-communication) for a full list).

About your second question, allow me to cite the beam [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/basics/#pcollection) and [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pcollections)

> A PCollection is a large, immutable “bag” of elements. There is **no**
> **upper limit** on how many elements a PCollection can contain; any given
> PCollection **might fit in memory** on a single machine, or it **might**
> represent a **very large** distributed data set **backed by a persistent**
> **data store**.

Comment: Thanks. Its interesting that you can mutate pcollections

Comment: Mutating PCollections (or rather their elements) is not allowed by the model, and in languages that don't have immutable objects we can't prohibit it but doing so will result in undefined (and often non-deterministic) behavior.