# Messed up data in Dataflow python SDK pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In google dataflow with python sdk i have the following pipeline

```
class LogElement(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        logging.info(f'{element}')
        yield element

class TestPTransform1(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        TestPTransform1__S1 = (pcoll
                        | Common(self.config)
                        )
        TestPTransform1__S3 = (TestPTransform1__S1 | TestPTransform2(self.config)
                        )

        TestPTransform1__S4 = (
                TestPTransform1__S3 | 'LogElement__TestPTransform1__S3-1' >> beam.ParDo(LogElement()) | TestPTransform3(
            self.config)
        )

        TestPTransform1__S6 = (TestPTransform1__S3 | 'LogElement__TestPTransform1__S3-3' >> beam.ParDo(LogElement()) | TestPTransform4(
            self.config))

        TestPTransform1__S5 = (TestPTransform1__S3 | 'LogElement__TestPTransform1__S3-2' >> beam.ParDo(LogElement()) | TestPTransform5(
            self.config)
                        | CommonWriteSnapshot(self.config)
                        )

        return TestPTransform1__S3
```

Im wondering why im getting different outputs in
`LogElement__TestPTransform1__S3-1`, `LogElement__TestPTransform1__S3-2`, `LogElement__TestPTransform1__S3-3`. Supposed to be identical - see pic.
[image]

Sometimes one of these outputs data that is supposed to get out of `TestPTransform5` which is downstream and on a different branch.
Other times just in the same logging node I get both: data that comes out of `TestPTransform1__S3`  as its suppose to be and data form `TestPTransform5`

The pipeline I have is branched and uses side outputs. Each side output is unique though and the main output always yields as an element without any tag.

Pipeline only does simple DoFn-based classes, no windowing, groupbykey or ordering at all.

The issue persists in both streaming and batching versions of the pipeline.

These are pipeline options:

```
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(runner='DataflowRunner,
                                   streaming=True,
                                   project='XXX',
                                   region='us-east1',
                                   job_name=JOB_NAME,
                                   temp_location=f'gs://XXX/temp/{JOB_NAME}',
                                   staging_location=f'gs://XXX/staging/{JOB_NAME}',
                                   service_account_email='XXXiam.gserviceaccount.com',
                                   setup_file='[PATH TO setup.py]'

                                   )
```

I wonder what may cause this mismatch and how to fix it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you sometimes see output which seems to have gone through another `PTransform` as you would expect from your DAG tree? That is most likely due to the fact, that you manipulate `TestPTransform1__S3` in any of the subsequent `PTransforms`. Any manipulation along the way is propagated along each step of the PCollection. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74866729/16622985)