# Apache Beam: Wait N seconds after window closes to execute DoFn

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have real time data being published and read into a Dataflow pipeline in a synchronous manner.

I collect the data, window it (1 second fixed) with accumulation then write it to a Firestore DB.
This DB is being watched by a front end and when new data arrives the front end automatically pulls in the snapshot.

The behaviour I'm seeing is that the front end data arrival is not synchronous, with inconsistent delays between data arrival.

I've been looking into stateful and timely functions and I think it could solve my problem, but I can't work out how to implement it since I'm not batching any data which to my understanding means I should just use a timely `DoFn`.

The data has been windowed and grouped by key, then aggregated with a custom function. The structure of the data being passed into the `DoFn` is a single nested python dictionary with multiple different data structures inside it.

```py
# class to write to firestore using DoFn
class WriteToFirestore(beam.DoFn):
    TIMER = userstate.TimerSpec('timer', userstate.TimeDomain.WATERMARK)
    BUFFER_STATE = userstate.BagStateSpec('buffer', WindowedValueCoder(MapCoder(str, str)))

    def setup(self):
        from google.cloud import firestore
        self.firestore_client = firestore.Client(project='project ID')

    def process(self, element,
            timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(TIMER),
            window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam,
            buffer_state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE)):
        logging.info("PROCESSING FUNCTION")

        timer.set(window.end + Duration(0.5)) # expire 0.5 seconds after window closes

        buffer_state.add(element)

    @userstate.on_timer(TIMER)
    def expiry(self):
        logging.info("FIRED")
        #collection_ref = self.firestore_client.collection('collection id')
        #collection_ref.add(event)
```

Pipeline Steps:

```py
# define pipeline steps
data = (
    pipeline
    | 'Read from PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=self.topic_path)
    | 'Proto to Dict' >> beam.Map(lambda pb_message: proto_to_dict(pb_message, msgs_pb2.Message))
    | 'Add Key' >> beam.Map(lambda message: add_group_key(message, SETTINGS))
    | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(
        window.FixedWindows(self.window_length),
        accumulation_mode=beam.trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING,
    )
    | 'Group' >> beam.GroupByKey()
    | 'Fuse' >> beam.Map(lambda group_messages: fuse(group_messages, SETTINGS, NODES))
)
        
# branch 1: Write to BigQuery
data | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
    'table ID',
     dataset='dataset ID',
     schema=TABLE_SCHEMA,
     write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
     create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
)
        
# branch 2: Publish to PubSub
data | 'Write to Firestore' >> beam.ParDo(WriteToFirestore())
```

This is the current code, it throws that the `Number of components doesn't match number of coders` - surely I only have 1 component?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the pipeline run, or is this error immediately thrown? If it is running, it could be that your `data` is 'empty' after the successful writing to BigQuery. Should this be the case, you should see some output in the table.

Comment: The pipeline does run, but as soon as I start publishing data over Pub/Sub it falls over. I know that the BigQuery branch runs because I can see data in the table. Does this mean that the Firestore branch may be empty? I don't see how that can be the case if the flow is split

Comment: You may mutate `PCollection`s in Python, however, it is not allowed by Beam. This results in non-deterministic behavior (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74858961/in-apache-beam-can-pcollections-be-reused-will-they-be-recomputed-or-can-they/74866729#74866729)). I am suspecting that `WriteToBigQuery` mutates the incoming data and thus you see your error. If I am right, you should be able to run your pipeline without this error, if you simply comment out the BigQuery output.

Comment: @CaptainNabla thank you for the detailed explanation and example. I think I understand where the error is originating from.